# Sorting an array by the values of another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a some messy data coming in from a feed, and am trying to figure out how to sort it correctly.  I posted a simplified example below.  I'd like to sort the people array alphabetically by the Group name.

```
$people = array( 
    "category_id_1" => array (
        "Mark",
        "Jenny",    
        "Andrew"
    ),
    "category_id_2" => array (
        "John",
        "Lewis",    
        "Andrea"
    ),
    "category_id_3" => array (
        "Hannah",
        "Angie",    
        "Raleigh"
    )
);

$categories = array( 
    "category_id_1" => "Group B",
    "category_id_2" => "Group C",
    "category_id_3" => "Group A"
);
```

Ideally, the end result would be

```
$people = array( 
    "category_id_3" => array ( // Group A
        "Hannah",
        "Angie",    
        "Raleigh"
    ),
    "category_id_1" => array ( // Group B
        "Mark",
        "Jenny",    
        "Andrew"
    ),
    "category_id_2" => array ( // Group C
        "John",
        "Lewis",    
        "Andrea"
    )
);
```

I've been spinning my wheels for a while now, and the closest I have gotten is this uasort, which still isn't doing the trick.

```
uasort($people, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($categories[$a], $categories[$b]);
});
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in a simpler way by taking advantage of `array_replace`:

```
// Work on a copy just to be sure the rest of your code is not affected
$temp_categories = $categories;
// Sort categories by name
asort($temp_categories);
// Replace the values of the sorted array with the ones in $people
$ordered_people = array_replace($temp_categories, $people);
```

Comment: That is the best answer +1 for array_replace

Comment: really? let me test it

Comment: @AmrBerag, the last edit fixed the problem. Now it does work.

Comment: True .. after fixing it its working now: asort($categories);
$result = array_replace($categories,$people);
Var_dump($result); i will edit my answer. thank you.

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.

Comment: It was failing because the function returns a boolean and not an array.The function affects the input array it self.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort `$people` by its keys not its values. You can use `uksort` for this. Additionally you need to make `$categories` available in your function. I prefer `use` for that; but you could also make it a global variable. Final code:

```
uksort($people, function ($a,$b) use ($categories) {
  return strcmp($categories[$a], $categories[$b]);
});
```

[Manual for uksort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uksort.php)

[use language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Before example 3.

Answer (score -1):

Try this(tested and working):

```
asort($categories);
$sorted = array();
foreach ($categories as $key => $value)
  $sorted[$key]=$people[$key];
```

A better shorter approach:(tested and working)

```
asort($categories);
$result = array_merge($categories,$people);
```

The second method takes advantage of the fact that array_merge function replace the values in the first array with those in the second one when keys are the same.
***warning*** : *The second approach will not work if the keys are numbers. Use only string keys with it. Furthermore if the categories array has entries without corresponding entries in the people array they will be copied to the result*

To solve this problem we use array_replace :

```
asort($categories);
$result = array_replace($categories,$people);
Var_dump($result);// tested and working
```

Comment: You have just copy pasted all the other answers to your answer, bit by bit. Look at the edit history. From an answer that does not work due to `sort` function to the current state

Comment: only the last one from Vlad and I commented in his answer but you copied my answer.Its true i forgot the a in asort but it was a typo.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is to Asort categories and the use that sorted array in a foreach.

```
Asort($categories);

Foreach($categories as $key => $group){
    $new[$key] =$people[$key];
}
Var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/kDAQW

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["category_id_3"]=> array(3) {
    [0]=> "Hannah"
    [1]=> "Angie"
    [2]=> "Raleigh"
  }
  ["category_id_1"]=> array(3) {
    [0]=> "Mark"
    [1]=> "Jenny"
    [2]=> "Andrew"
  }
  ["category_id_2"]=>array(3) {
    [0]=> "John"
    [1]=> "Lewis"
    [2]=> "Andrea"
  }
}
```